# how to replace <br> tag with <br/> tag using HtmlAgilityPack?

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

Quite strange!
When I load & replace  with an empty string using

```
 var document = new HtmlDocument();
    document.LoadHtml(data); 
    document.DocumentNode.OuterHtml.Replace("<tbody>", "");
```

**This works fine & `<tbody>` will be removed.**

Same way when I try to replace `<br>`  with `<br/>` using,

```
document.DocumentNode.OuterHtml.Replace("<br>", "<br/>");
```

**It does not work :(**

also tried,

```
 var brTags = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//br");
            if (brTags != null)
            {
                foreach (HtmlNode brTag in brTags)
                {
                    brTag.OuterHtml = "<br/>";
                    // brTag.Name= "br/"; - > Also this one :(
                }
            }
```

HTMLAgilityPack's replace() function does not work for self closing tags?

Comment: I believe that in HTML, `br` is a self closing tag and so `<br/>` is invalid HTML. It may be that the pack is trying to keep the result valid.

Comment: Want it to be in `<br/>` format only even thou `<br>` is valid!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
document.OptionWriteEmptyNodes = true;
```

Will do the trick for you!

Answer (score 7):

You don't have to replace `<br>` by `<br/>` manually, if you need to close the node, just instruct the library to do so, for example this:

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml("<br/>");
doc.Save(Console.Out);
```

will output this:

```
<br>
```

and this

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml("<br/>");
doc.OptionWriteEmptyNodes = true;
doc.Save(Console.Out);
```

will output this:

```
<br />
```

Comment: @user2729272 - why did you marked the other one as answer since it's a latter copy of this one?

Comment: i try "doc.OptionWriteEmptyNodes = true;"   Works fine.

Answer (score 2):

```
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
var xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(writer, new XmlWriterSettings() { OmitXmlDeclaration = true });
document.OptionOutputAsXml = true;

document.Save(xmlWriter);
var newHtml = writer.ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually your first query also should not work if you do not assign result of replacement back to document. Strings are immutable in C#. When you do `Replace` new string is created and returned. Original string stays unchanged.

Also `OuterHtml` is read-only. You cannot assign it.

In order to remove nodes you should select them, remove each, and save result to original string.

```
var document = new HtmlDocument();
document.LoadHtml(data);
foreach (var tbody in document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//tbody"))
    tbody.Remove();
data = document.DocumentNode.OuterHtml;
```

UPDATE:

```
foreach (var br in document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//br"))
    br.RemoveAllChildren();

HtmlNode.ElementsFlags["br"] = HtmlElementFlag.Closed | HtmlElementFlag.Empty;
document.OptionWriteEmptyNodes = true;
data = document.DocumentNode.OuterHtml;
```